# Django localization not working "DjangoCMS"

Tags: django-cms

Am working on DjangoCMS project. In which i have developed some Django Apps and plugin to it.

Basically my project in two languages EN, IT and its working fine DjangoCMS level. But i want to use Internationalization & Localization for my Django Apps and some static form heading. So i have used Django default Internationalization and Localization.

By this django created a .po and .mo file in my local path that i defined in settings.py. 
But .po `msgid "BlogCategory"
msgstr "BlogCategoryEN"` are not translating in templates.

Can any one guide where am doing wrong. My code is bellow:

settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
## Customize this
('en', gettext('en')),
('it', gettext('it')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'locale')
)
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
## Customize this
'default': {
    'public': True,
    'hide_untranslated': True,
    'redirect_on_fallback': True,
},
1: [
    {
        'public': True,
        'code': 'en',
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'name': gettext('en'),
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
    },
    {
        'public': True,
        'code': 'it',
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'name': gettext('it'),
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
    },
],
}
```

/home/ranjeet/PycharmProjects/wakuseo/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
/home/ranjeet/p/project/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo

```
#: easy_blog/models.py:29
msgid "Blog List Banner"
msgstr "Blog List Banner EN"
```

template.html

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles %}
{% load l10n i18n %}
{% trans 'Blog List Banner'  %}
```

It should be print "Blog List Banner EN" but printing "Blog List Banner". That mean trans is not working on template.

Pleas help how i can solve this.

Note: Project in DjangoCMS and have create some apps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but have you run...?

```
    python manage.py compilemessages --locale=en
```

Have you restarted your server after running that command?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yours answers.

I got solution: It was wrong in settings.py, i have forgot to add comma (,) in

```
`LOCALE_PATHS = (
os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'locale')
)`
```

So now is:

```
`LOCALE_PATHS = (
os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'locale'),
)`
```

Its working fine for me.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: I was about to ask you about your LOCALE_PATHS :-)